# gradle get relative resource path

Tags: groovy, gradle

When I iterate over source repository I do like this

```
def resourceDir = proj.sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
resourceDir.eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { // only files will be recognized
   file ->
      def path = FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(file.toString())
      if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.toString()) in supportedResourceExt) {
         proj.logger.lifecycle("Reading file {}.", file) 
         //.....
      }
 }
```

In log it writes this

```
Reading file D:\PROJECT_FOLDER\project\subproject\subsubproject\build\resources\main\com\package\something\file.txt
```

How to get only the part starting with `com\package\something\file.txt` without explicitly reading it like `file.substring(file.indexOf)`?

Maybe it's posible to relativize it with project path somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that:

```
proj.logger.lifecycle("Reading file {}.", file.absolutePath - resourceDir.absolutePath)
```

should work. Can't check it right now.